Could it be illegal to intentionally "poison" AI crawling?
There is a youtube about generating images with features designed to "poison" generative AI trained on those images.
This technique could potentially be used by anyone who was worried about their content being harvested by AI's.  On any website distributing such content one could have "honeypot items/scraper trap" that is targeted at distorting the creative content.  This could be images on an art website, as shown in the video.  This could be discordant sound on a music distribution site, badly written text on an author's website or fake news on a news website.  It is at least conceivable that this would make scraping the website for training data counter-productive, and so protect the content.
Would there be any legal issues with doing this?  One would be intentionally causing "damage" to a computer system, which means one may consider Computer Misuse Act 1990 in the UK and Computer Fraud and Abuse Act in the US.  One could imagine that for a web site accessible globally one should consider all jurisdictions.

If you put a statement on your site that you do not authorize the use of your images to train AI, and explicitly mention that you take active measure to prevent this (without necessarily explaining your methods in detail), then anyone doing so will be in violation of your site's terms of use. State that by using your site, visitors agree to the terms, and put an "I agree" checkbox and button. This would make it much more difficult for someone running an AI bot to pretend they were victimized by your site, as they would have to admit that they violated your site's terms to train their AI.

Additionally, you could add to the terms that users agree not to hold you or anyone involved in maintaining the site liable for damage that may occur to their data sets should they use images or other content from your site in ways that go against the terms. Whining that one's data set developed "problems" due to crawling "poisoned" images is pretty frivolous to begin with. But if you state your policy clearly then it should be obvious there isn't any deliberate deception on your part, and that the so-called "poisoning" is a protective measure to prevent the misuse of your data.

Isn't this similar to fictitious entry?

Examples of this already exist. I recall seeing a website that just consists of 3 random images with links behind them. Each link just leads to the same website with 3 different random images. Aparently this caught some bots who loaded this website several thousand times.

From a purely technological point of view, it could be argued that this is not causing any damage. By design, the AI generates content similar to the content of the websites it visits. If you poison your website, the AI is still working perfectly as intended.

I could see a similar question about honeypots that are sometimes used in cybersecurity to help catch cybercriminals and/or deflect attacks from valuable systems.

Is there a robots.txt file indicating to the crawler that it should not crawl the site?

A comparison could be made to distributing malware. Like the AI case, the file itself doesn't do anything until someone feeds it into a specific computer system that the file is designed to affect negatively.

@AndrewMorton That's the correct way of implementing Mentalist's suggestion. An automated crawler can't be expected to parse and understand legal disclaimers in plain text; the robots.txt protocol was designed specifically so there would be a machine-readable version of those.

united-kingdom
A necessary element of each offence in the Computer Misuse Act 1990 is "unauthorised access" or an "unauthorised act" with respect to a computer. E.g. section 3:

3 Unauthorised acts with intent to impair, or with recklessness as to impairing, operation of computer, etc.
(1) A person is guilty of an offence if—
(a) he does any unauthorised act in relation to a computer; ...

It seems to me that I am authorised to access and act on a computer that I own. So in effect it seems you're asking whether "any unauthorised act in relation to a computer" can be interpreted to apply to something I do to my computer that impairs another computer that crawls my computer without my consent or even knowledge.
In the absence of relevant case law - which doesn't seem to exist - we can only speculate as to whether the law might be interpreted so broadly. Computer Misuse Act cases seem to be about access to computers the defendant (A) did not have permission to access at all or (B) did not have permission to access for the specific purpose of the defendant.
I would say that sinkholes and tarpits relate to a computer owner deliberately configuring their computer to impair certain types of unwanted and unauthorised visits by other computers but neither of those seem to be illegal acts in the UK.
Which suggests another point: the owner of the unwanted, unauthorised computer visitor would have to make a complaint to attempt to have me prosecuted or sued for my act with respect to my computer, but if what they attempted is itself unlawful then they would be unlikely to make such a complaint.

"but if what they attempted is itself unlawful then they would be unlikely to make such a complaint" - there were cases of burglars who got injured during the burglary and successfully sued the owner of the home they invaded, for damages. One category of such cases are booby traps, but there were even cases where the burglars won because they were injured due to negligence of the owner to maintain the property, making it unsafe.

@vsz Of course if such cases became very common, the obvious solution would be to make your booby traps so good that the burglars have no chance of making it out alive to sue. We can see this in countries where hitting a pedestrian accidentally is usually followed by rolling over them several more times to make sure they're dead.

@vsz Legislation in England and Wales says that in some circumstances the occupier has a duty to persons other than his visitors. That's how some injured burglars can sue and win. Is there similar law that applies in the context of this question?

It would be hard to argue "another computer that crawls my computer without my consent or even knowledge", when you intentionally connect your computer to the internet and make its contents accessible thru a web server.

@brhans: It's really not hard at all.  Look at the difference between points (A) and (B) in the answer.  Totally valid to claim that the public does have permission to visit the web server for the purpose of displaying content to an interactive human user, but not for the purpose of scraping the content for further analysis (and in particular not for AI training)

As you already figured out, the UK's Computer Misuse Act 1990 applies. It specifically says (section 36) that "This subsection applies if the person intends by doing the act ... to impair the ... the reliability of any such data; " and goes on to state that "The intention referred to ... need not relate to
(a)any particular computer; (b)any particular program or data; or (c)a program or data of any particular kind" so AI data is included.
However, there's another part to this: is it unauthorized ? That would need to be considered in context. After all, the hypothetical here is that the data is modified by the legal owner of the data. If that is the only act, that modification is authorized. But as soon as you lure any AI scraper to that data, the latter act would be a problem because that was not authorized.

isn't the AI owner's use of the other data unauthorised to begin with?

@Trish: The legal problem with AI training is that it's a new, unforeseen type of use. It's neither authorized nor forbidden by law. There's a growing consensus about explicitly denying access (robots.txt), and there's a reasonable expectation that will hold in court.

The theory I proffer with the comment is, that the AI owner either a) has no rights to the image in the first place, and his use is barred b) by still using the image did the damage to himself, and can't hold the artist liable.

@MSalters I don't think that scraping anything that's not protected by robots.txt or otherwise is forbidden in any way; I mean, it's online, duh. What is possibly forbidden is to give it a thorough shake and a stir, and spit it back out, without attribution. That is forbidden for humans and machines alike, there is no difference. Now, in the end, we all absorb texts and produce texts which contain very few, if any, original thoughts, which implies that we essentially mix, stir and spit it back out, too. The question is essentially how much re-wording and re-arranging is necessary.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: Why would attribution matter? Here on StackOverflow it's a CC BY-SA contractual requirement, but if you assume "it's online duh" then you are assuming unrestricted access.

@MSalters In Germany, the Urheberrechtsgesetz (copyright law) allows some uses like citations but requires that the source be named to protect the owner's copyright. I assume that similar laws exist in U.S. jurisdictions, which is why the New York Times sues OpenAI. "Online duh" was intended to emphasize the truism that online content is freely and intentionally readable (after all, somebody put it out for everybody to see). It did not mean that the content be freely reproducible/re-distributable.
